# Making classes the purely exists for adopting delegates

Tags: iphone

Is it normal, even possible to make classes that adopts the required and optional method such as in UITableViewDataSource. Then assign an object of this class as delegate in the UITableView?

Or is inheritance to be preffered?

Comment: UITableViewDataSource is a protocol, not a class

Comment: It's possible, but would be trickier that just subclassing `UITableView`. Is there some particular reason you had in mind for separating the data source, or are you just curious? (And by the way, the class that implements `UITableViewDataSource` should be referenced by the `dataSource` property, not the `delegate` property, just to be clear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all:
See the [Apple's Objective-C guide's protocol section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1).

```
@interface MyTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate> {
    // Declare instance variables here
}
// Declare other methods here, the delegate methods are optional, but not necessary
@end
```

The class above conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate`. To let the compiler know it does, you have to put it between a `<` and a `>` (I don't know how they're called). To let the compiler know it conforms to multiple protocols, separate them by commas:

```
@interface MyTableViewDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    // Declare instance variables here
}
// Declare other methods here, the protocol methods 
// can be declared but it's not necessary
@end
```

You can also cast an object to let it conform to a protocol. Though this is not recommended. If an object does not implement a required function of the protocol, an exception probably will be thrown.

Casting:

```
[aTableView setDelegate:(id <UITableViewDelegate)myNotDeclaredAsDelegateThoughIsTableViewDelegateObject];
```

Hope it helps,
ief2

Comment: "You can also cast an object to let it conform to a protocol." That's a little misleading. While it's true that the cast may bypass the compile-time check, protocols can be checked dynamically, so you'd have to be certain of the underlying implementation (a dependency you should always try to avoid) to know whether this would work at runtime, unless it's explicitly spelled out in Apple's docs.

Comment: You're right. I should have written "You can cast an object to let it seam to conform to a protocol"

Answer (score 0):

Why not? a UITableView's data source and delegate don't have to be the UITableViewController. Just assign the right object(s) to the table view's `dataSource` and `delegate` properties, and implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols, respectively.

Comment: But then again, why would you? Just because something's possible doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @jlehr, it has every reason to be a good idea if your app is a little more complex than Apple's sample code.